# Wine Environment Variables

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to launch Eclipse on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer using Wine but I need to set an Environment Variable to javaw.exe for it to run. I have consulted the Wine User Guide and couldn't understand it. https://dl.winehq.org/wine/docs/en/wineusr-guide.pdf

If you could help that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry pal. But this is not a [\[ valid\]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question.  Please consider migrating it to [\[ askubuntu \]](http://askubuntu.com). For that you may click [\[ flag \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680601/wine-environment-variables#) and request a moderator to do migrate this one.

Comment: Wrong site. Questions regarding how to set environmental variables in Wine are not about programming. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are on-topic here.

Comment: Thanks I will try that